# select a numeric column as string

Tags: sql, sas, proc, converters

Is it possible to select a numeric column as string with proc sql in sas ?

for exemple i have this table (table_1):

```
+------+------+------+--------------+--+
| id_1 | id_2 | id_3 |     date     |  |
+------+------+------+--------------+--+
|    3 |    7 |    3 |  25/06/2017  |  |
|    4 |   11 |    9 |  25/06/2020  |  |
+------+------+------+--------------+--+
```

id_1, id_2 and id_3 can be numeric or string.

i want to create a table (table_2) where these three columns should have string as type

I wrote this code :

```
proc sql;

Create table table_2 as 

select date, Convert(varchar(30),a.id_1), Convert(varchar(30),a.id_2), Convert(varchar(30),a.id_3)

from table_1   a

;quit;
```

But it doesn't works

Comment: "can be numeric or string" . . . Does SAS allow this?  SQL generally does not.

Comment: Yes, i mean since my table_1 change every month sometimes i receive id_1(id_2,id_3) as string and sometimes i receive it as integer.

Comment: How are you receiving the dataset?  You should fix in the source if you can.

Comment: Actually i receive data as sas tables !

Comment: So talk to whoever is sending the data and have them fix how they create them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best solution is to fix your up stream processes to always generate the variables using a consistent type.

In SAS you can use the PUT() function to convert a value to a string, just use a FORMAT that is appropriate for the type of the variable.  For example if your variable is number but it should have been 9 digits long with significant leading zeros then you would want to use the Z9. format to convert it and have the leading zeros represented.

```
 select put(id_1,z9.) as id_1
```

If you want to convert either a number or a character variable to a string without first knowing the type of the variable you could use the CATS() function.  But then you will not have any control over how the numbers are converted into strings.  Use the LENGTH= attribute to force SAS to define the variable with a length of 30.

```
 select cats(id_1) as id_1 length=30
```

Comment: Thank  you so much the function cats resolve perfectly my problem

Answer (score 0):

Just Try It ...

```
SELECT date, CAST(a.id_1 AS varchar(30)), CAST(a.id_2 AS varchar(30)), CAST(a.id_3 AS varchar(30))
FROM table_1   a
```

Comment: Why `varchar(30)`? Do you expect the numeric values to be 30 digits long?

Comment: No expect  Anything . Its Just a Size your String

Comment: Not sure what dialect of SQL you are using here but there is neither a `CAST()` nor a `CONVERT()` function in SAS's implementation of SQL.